# Android: Playing MIDI Notes Using Handler and Scrolling RecyclerView Accordingly

Tags: android

I am playing MIDI notes using [this](https://github.com/kshoji/javax.sound.midi-for-Android) library as follows:

```
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        ShortMessage message;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            {
                MidiEvent event = midiEvents.get(index[0]);
                if (index[0] < midiEvents.size() - 1) {
                    delta = midiEvents.get(index[0] + 1).getDelta();
                    time[0] = timeFactor * midiEvents.get(index[0] + 1).getDelta();
                    mTotalMidiTime += time[0];
                    int noteValue;
                    int NOTE_STATUS;
                    if (event instanceof NoteOn) {
                        noteValue = ((NoteOn) event).getNoteValue();
                        NOTE_STATUS = NOTE_ON;
                        if (index[0] != 0) {
                            if (delta != 0) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent();
                                intent.setAction(Constants.SCROLL_RECYCLERVIEW);
                                localBroadcastManager.sendBroadcast(intent);
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        noteValue = ((NoteOff) event).getNoteValue();
                        NOTE_STATUS = NOTE_OFF;
                    }
                    try {
                        message = new ShortMessage(NOTE_STATUS, 2, noteValue,
                                127);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setAction(Constants.ACTION_SEEK);
                    localBroadcastManager.sendBroadcast(intent);
                    if (message != null)
                        recv.send(message, -1);
                    index[0]++;
                } else {
                    index[0] = 0;
                    time[0] = 1;
                    mTotalMidiTime = mMinimumTime;
                    delta = 0;
                }

                handler.postDelayed(this, time[0]);
            }
        }
    }, 0);
```

With each `NoteOn` event I am smooth scrolling a `RecyclerView` and updating a Seekbar using a `LocalBroadcastManager`
My problem is that playback is fine when UI operations are not performed but playback and UI get completely out of sync as soon as multiple MIDI notes (chords) are played in very quick succession. It would be appreciated if any performance improvements are suggested for the same. I have already tried performing the UI operations in `runOnUiThread` and also launching a new `Handler` for UI operations.

My `BroadcastReceiver` is as follows:

```
    BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String actionType = intent.getAction();
        switch (actionType) {
            case Constants.SCROLL_RECYCLERVIEW:
                Handler handler  = new Handler();
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mNotesRecycler.smoothScrollBy(pixels, 0);
                    }
                });
                break;
            case Constants.ACTION_SEEK:
                Handler seekHandler = new Handler();
                seekHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mPinchSeekBar.setSelectedCentreValue(mTotalMidiTime);
                        mCurrentTime.setText(timeInMinutes((int) mTotalMidiTime));
                    }
                });

                break;

        }

    }
};
```

Comment: The root of the problem is on how you perform the smoothscroll. Can you post the corresponding source? Also, I does the seekbar also goes out of sync or, as I suspect, only the recyclerview?

Comment: @rupps Your suspicion stands correct, it's the RecyclerView that's out of sync. If I turn on the seekbar as well, the overall performance of the app decreases, thus making it extremely sluggish. I've also added the code for UI handling.

Comment: I will post a more elaborate answer tonight, but as a starter, do not create a new `Handler` for every note, that's a performance killer itself and a waste of resources. Just one `Handler` is enough to post stuff

Comment: Sorry, but did you mean a new Runnable here?

Answer (score 0):

Besides the optimizations you can do, I think the problem itself is `RecyclerView's` `smoothScroll` is  more a method you call sometimes to do a fancy scroll rather  than bomb it with requests that cause it to constantly recompute the running animation.

One thing you can try is to write yourself a simple scroll handler that calls `mRecyclerView.scrollTo()` that does the scroll without animation but I guess it's going to be more reliable.

Try something like this

```
Handler mHandler = new Handler();
int mPosition, mTargetPosition;

@IntRange(from = 20, to = 100)
final int INTERVAL = 50; // try with 50 ms or a little lower  

Runnable mTimerScroll = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

        if (mPosition != mTargetPosition) {
           if (mPosition < mTargetPosition) {
               mPosition += mDelta;
               if (mPosition > mTargetPosition) mPosition = mTargetPosition;
            }
            if (mPosition > mTargetPosition) {
               mPosition -= mDelta;
               if (mPosition < mTargetPosition) mPosition = mTargetPosition;
            }

            mRecyclerView.scrollTo(mPosition, 0);
         }       

         // repeat every 50ms
         mTimerScroll.post(mRunnable, INTERVAL);

    }
}
```

And then you start it

```
void startTimer() {
   stop(); // prevent double start
   mHandler.post(mTimerScroll);
}
void stopTimer() {
   mHandler.removeCallbacks(mTimerScroll);
}
void scroll(int target) {
   mTargetPosition = target;
}
void scrollBy(int pixels) {
   scroll(mPosition + pixels);
}
```

I don't know the specifics of your app but it might work.

About optimization, you are using a lot of stuff there that can or cannot be necessary depending on the specifics of your library, etc, but if there are no different threads or services involved you could avoid the `LocalBroadcast` thing and all the `handler.post()` as everything is already on the UI thread (`handler.post` just posts a runnable to the thread where the handler was created, that in your case is the UI thread, so it doesn't do anything)

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer. I'll try this out and get back to you.